# void* C++ equivalent C#

Tags: c#, c++, casting, void

I'm currently encountering a problem with a line of code in C++ that I'd like to convert to C#.

```
struct card {
    bool operator()(void* const & c1, void* const & c2) const;
};
```

I've tried different things like an IntPtr but I think I got the syntax wrong.

Comment: that is a very very bad C++ code. Besides that we need to know what the `c1` and `c2` are expected to be and what is being done with them. Otherwise the question is unanserable.

Comment: c1 and c2 are int that sorts out the effects of the players' cards on the field.

Comment: What is that line of code supposed to *do*? If you don't tell us we can't tell you how to convert it.

Comment: If they're `int`s, why not accept `int` parameters?

Comment: Perhaps something with `unsafe` keyword?

Comment: C# has `void*`. So the equivalent is `void*`. Why?

Comment: If parameters are ints then just make this nightmare a simple bool Get(int c1, int c2); method. Somebody tried to be too smart with this C++ code